# Append jQuery code into iframe does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I encounter a very strange problem!

I wrote the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="code">
    <div id="hello">Hello world!</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#hello").css({"border":"solid 3px red"});
        alert($("#hello").size());
    });
    </script>
</textarea>

<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("iframe").on("load",function(){
            $(this).contents().find("body").append($("#code").val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

The "iframe.html" file contains only a call to the jQuery library.

The result is that "Hello world!" is displayed in the iframe but without red border! It seems that `$("#hello")` does not work. In fact, if I do `alert($("#hello").size())`, I get "0".

Do you have any idea?
Thanks!

Edit: Add "alert".

Answer (score 0):

I think the html format is wrong. You are putting the `div` inside the text area and inside any text area if you put some html elements then those are simply taken as some text and that html elements are not going to render in browser.
So you can put the the div element out side the text area.

```
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
<div id="hello">Hello world!</div>
```

I hope this will work.. :)

Comment: I made a mistake when I simplified my problem. The code that is in the textarea is encoded into HTML entities. However, this error seems to have no consequence.

Answer (score 0):

$(this).contents().find("body").append($("#code").val());
Only gets the current value so probably it wont copy over any css value that is linked to it.
http://api.jquery.com/val/

What I suggest is testing it in 1 file first to see what it does so remove the iframe part for now and check the .size() on 1 file. that way you know how the .val and .size() behave on your #hello.

Try this as the script under the :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("iframe").on("load",function(){
alert($("#code").val());
    var scriptx = $("#code").val();
    $(this).contents().find("body")[0].innerHTML = scriptx;
        });
    });
</script>
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Without the iframe part, it works very well. You can see http://jsfiddle.net/ZzVCF/

Comment: If you add this:
$(this).contents().find("#hello").css({"border":"solid 3px red"});
You will see that it gives the border to it. which means it loads the div into the iframe page but not the javascript.

Comment: Where do I add this : `$(this).contents().find("#hello").css({"border":"solid 3px red"});` ? For information, my javascript code is well executed because my "alert" works. The problem really seems to come from jQuery.

Comment: Test this as a different code:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        $("iframe").on("load",function(){
    var script = $("#code");
    var scriptx = $("<div />").html(script).text();
    alert(scriptx);
    var body = $(this).contents().find("body");
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = scriptx;    
        });
    });
</script>
This since jQuery filters out the script tags when retrieving the html.

Comment: I tried this : `$(function(){ $("iframe").on("load",function(){ var script = $("#code"); var scriptx = $("<div />").html(script).text(); alert(scriptx); $(this).contents().find("body")[0].innerHTML = scriptx; }); });` without success. Moreover: my textarea disappears.

Comment: Edited the above code. it now loads the script in the iframe content as you can see in the element inspector. the main problem is it won't execute the javascript in the iframe even when it's added to it.

Comment: I tried this yesterday and indeed the javascript code is not executed. I think that there is no simple solution to do what I want. I'll find another way.

Comment: There is a solution you could let the iframe.onload javascript function find all script tags and execute them through the function.

Comment: I found another solution: instead of the parent window injects code in the iframe, the iframe gets the code from the parent window! In this direction: it works. This may be caused by security browsers.